# Escaping Contents of HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, escaping, special-characters

I'm running a function to cycle through elements on a email newsletter and escape HTML.

```
function escapeChars() {
    iframe.contents().find('[data-mailbuilder="article-content"]')
    .children()
    .each(function() {
        $(this).text(escapeHtml($(this).text()));
    });
}


function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

However jQuery seems to replace '&' with '&amp;' without actually escaping the character.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using `.text()` instead of `.html()`, why do you need to escape it?

Comment: The application creates emails using a wysiwyg. When the HTML of the iframe is downloaded it needs to use the Unicode instead of the character itself.

Comment: What do you mean by _without actually escaping the character_?

Comment: So when the Text is added back into it's element. it added as the literal unicode character. the "&amp;" isn't rendered.

Comment: That's the difference between `.text()` and `.html()`. The latter renders it as HTML code, the former shows it literally.

Answer (score 0):

To render it as an html use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. So, change it to:

```
$(this).html(escapeHtml($(this).text()));
```

Comment: Changing the .text() to .html() didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did u change it to: $(this).html(escapeHtml($(this).text()));

Comment: Yes, what that seem's to do is not change it to the escaped character at all.